# Exclude one metaball from interacting with another metaball only

Tags: animation, meta-objects

In the image below, Is there a way to make A and B not interacting with each other, but both interact with the U meta-balls?

[image]

I need to prevent A (specific metaball) from connecting to B even if there surfaces intersect, but both (A and B) should keep connected to the U.

Hard to explain.

Comment: I don't think so, if A and B don't interact, then one of the two won't be able to interact with U, so you should find a trick, like for example there is U and U' that don't interact

Comment: @moonboots The connections will keep showing behind U', tried it before. or maybe I didn't understand your idea.

Comment: I mean you can pretend that your U shape is one unique shape whereas in fact it would be two independent shapes, you could also make a traditional mesh for this U then put metaballs inside this mesh to simulate all the interactions with A and B... actually it really depends on what U is supposed to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't much that can be done in this case. Metaballs do not have a lot of functionality in Blender. You could just insert a plane between them and set it to negative. It does deform them, so it is not ideal, but there are no other solutions as far as I am aware if you want to keep them as metaballs.

[image]

Comment: Hehe.. jumped my comment! I also applied mixed 'Child of' and 'Damped Track' constraints on the plane, to keep it between the balls I wanted to insulate from one another, in the correct orientation.. But it's a fudge. What's really needed is isosurfaces  to be generated, not between balls in the same  name-family, but between balls in the same group, (with the possibility of a ball belonging to more than one group). That would greatly extend the usefulness of metaballs.

Comment: I think there are plenty of ways to improve metaballs in Blender, however they are not very popular and that might not be seen as a very attractive and exciting job by many developers.